# Subtle Tongue Ballet

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, steganography

> There is debris in this business. If you could for a minute, you'd say, "Damn! Show some muscle! Earn a plaque!"
>
> It's quiet parliament, like unseen islands.
>
> Less than phlegm, unheard by people. They can't talk! It's my pledge, in this minute: I quietly condemn.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This puzzle has a lot of

> words with silent letters.

Specifically:

> Every third word has one!
>
>  There is **debri[s]** in this **bus[i]ness**. If you **cou[l]d** for a **minut[e]**, you'd say, "**Dam[n]**! Show some **mus[c]le**! Earn a **plaqu[e]**!"
>
>  It's quiet **parl[i]ament**, like unseen **i[s]lands**.
>
>  Less than **phle[g]m**, unheard by **pe[o]ple**. They can't **ta[l]k**! It's my **ple[d]ge**, in this **minut[e]**: I quietly **condem[n]**.

A few of these are *slightly* ambiguous, but there's one clear way to resolve them (as I've marked above).

> The silent letters spell **SILENCE IS GOLDEN**.

Comment: Yes that is so true...and duct tape is silver...

Comment: ...and you can't go wrong with a bronze bullet.

Comment: Whoa, that escalated quickly, NL628 & @thecoder16 !

Comment: Hmm, this does make me wonder if I pronounce "Talk" and "Could" wrong...

Comment: [LOL @Phylyp!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rFeVfwDvTyM)